# average (annual) salaries for occupations in the UK

Tags: data-request, uk, europe

I have occupations like this:

```
Joiner
Fitter
Smelter
Electrician
```

and would like to obtain rough average (annual) salaries in the UK. Is anyone aware of such dataset(s)?